# Haskell Syntax: Adding ints from tuples in a list

Tags: haskell

I've searched the site but couldn't find anything specific to this problem..

I have a list that contains triples of `strings` and `integers` like so:

```
mylist = [("Amy", 6), ("Scott, 3"), ("Bradley", 4)]
```

I want to write a function that will just add up all the integers from this list

I currently have the function:

```
addMarks :: [(String, Int)] -> Int
addMarks pairList = [ j+j | (i,j) <- pairList ]
```

`j+j` doesn't work, I'm not sure on the correct syntax to add just the `'j'`s and leave the `i`.

Comment: List comprehensions always result in a list, so you can't solve this with only a list comprehension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to sum over the second value of a pair. There's a function for summing over the content of a list (`sum`), and there's a function for getting the second value of a pair (`snd`):

```
addMarks = sum . map snd
```

`map f` takes a list and returns a new list by applying `f` to every element. If you want to use list comprehension for this, you would end up with

```
addMarks pairList = sum [ j | (_,j) <- pairList ]
```

since list comprehension is just syntactic sugar for `filter` and `map`.